# Contact Form 7 Track submit fields errors

Tags: wordpress, forms, dom-events

I use this code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid', function( event ) {
ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'SubmitError');
}, false );
</script>
```

to track fileds errors.
Everthing is fine but i just want to add also the class of the filed, and track with dom-event wpcf7invalid also the class of the fileds.

Can someone help me with that? 
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just create one thank you page in your website and after submitting the form redirect to that page using contact form 7 function. You can find in contact configuration of each form in wp-admin.

After set this you can track a lead from Google analytics which user come from contact form to thank you page those all leads.

If you try to tracking means it will help you

Comment: what have this to do with my question?

Comment: I think you need to track the form submission in google analytics.